# Can civilians who buy ex-military fighter jets get the necessary maintenance information for them?

Tags: military, aircraft-maintenance, fighter, regulations

I was looking for fighter jets which are available to be bought by private citizens. I was wondering: how would you schedule the maintenance, as most of the jets are ex-military and there are no maintenance plans?

Comment: My suggestion would be to ask the manufacturer to provide you with the maintenance manuals.

Comment: and, maybe find a retired military maintenance officer or senior NCO and hire him.

Comment: Some fighters with larger followings, like the L-39 Albatross, you can find [service centers](https://www.code1aviation.com/) in different parts of the country to service them.

Comment: Actually for airworthiness certification of ex-military jets I believe they require you to obtain any/all declassified manuals, maintenance manuals, etc. on them. I know for a FACT to certify the Mig-21 they require you to own all the Mig-21 manuals (technical orders, maintenance manuals, parts catalogs, engine manuals, inspection schedules, flight manuals, and checklists) **sigh** I should have bought that mig. Biggest regret of my life.

Comment: And from these manuals it should be possible to have parts custom-fabricated; that's actually not difficult to get done it's just expensive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most military surplus aircraft are considered by the FAA to be experimental exhibition aircraft and subject to the rules and maintenance requirements for experimental aircraft.  That being said, most owners seek out retired military personnel who did maintenance on these aircraft and currently work as AIs (authorized inspectors) in civilian aviation to handle maintenance and repairs.  Firms like Code 1 Aviation and Thornton Aircraft specialize in certain types of military aircraft and have collected libraries of maintenance manuals and other resources for owners and can perform maintenance conforming to the old military and civilian experimental aircraft guidelines.

Comment: And what about the maintenance certificates for the mechanic? I read a lot of military aircraft mechanics do not get the kind of license a civilian mechanic has.

Comment: No, I’m talking about ex-military mechanics which obtain an AI from the FAA.

Comment: What exactly is an AI?

Comment: Authorized Inspector